# Laravel Artisan CLI doesn't execute commands

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, command-line-interface, laravel-artisan

The problem I'm facing with Laravel's (v4.2) Artisan CLI is that when I try to execute a command (for instance `php artisan list`) the command doesn't work and instead I get the contents of Illuminate\Foundation\Application object in Command Window.

[Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/q0ctgeh2p/)

Comment: You should edit your question and add the full stack trace. Most likely you have an error in your code that's preventing artisan to work. Without further details it will be impossible to pin point what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're question is vauge. But if what you're asking is about how to add custom commands to Laravel's Artisan, then you are probably missing the last step.

If you have already [created your command](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands#building-a-command) via:

```
php artisan command:make CustomCommand --command=custom:command
```

Then the last step that you need to do is to [register your command](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands#registering-commands):

```
Artisan::add(new CustomCommand);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually even when I type only `php artisan` I get the same output in Command Window (as shown in Screenshot above)... It's like Artisan doesn't respond at all...

Comment: Weird. Did you modify any of the core code? That doesn't look like a stack trace to me, it looks like you put a `print_r( ); exit( );` somewhere. Keep in mind that if your custom command has this, artisan will execute this when it is running ever the most basic commands, it does this to know the options available. Can you post your custom command code?

Comment: I don't have any custom command code.. It's a fresh Laravel installation. I guess something's wrong with the installation itself... I'll try to reinstall Laravel. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Either that, or try a `composer install` in the root of your directory. Perhaps something didn't finish downloading on install.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that but strangely didn't work while fresh install seems fine for now... Thanks again!